# Remove certain tags from html input with PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, sanitization

I have a form where users are able to style their own input with html. I want to clean that input on the server side with PHP. However, I want to make sure that all the input is secure and matches what I would like it to be. I already have XSS protection so this is **not about removing scripts.**

When the user provides input, I want to remove tags other than `p`, `img`, `a`, `hr`, `br`, `tbody`, `tr`, `td`, `pre`, `ul`, `ol`, `li` and `span` (basically all text formatting other than divs). I want to remove any attributes other than `href` for `<a>`, `src` for `<img>`, and `style` for `<p>`. For `<p>` style I would only like to preserve the following attributes:

- `color`
- `background-color`
- `line-height`
- Anything that starts with `text-`

In addition, I want to be able to crop the text to a certain length while preserving ending tags and making sure that every opening tag also has a closing tag.

For example, how does the Stack Overflow editor parse and clean input before saving it and displaying it to the user?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the code behind SO's editor. If you show us your code maybe we can help you improve it.

Comment: My code is coming from the Summernote editor. To clarify, this is about the backend.

Comment: Are you using CKEditor for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use http://htmlpurifier.org/ to clean html-input. You can define the tags, attributes and styles that are allowed. I added the code from my project as an example.

```
    $configuration = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $configuration->set('Attr.EnableID', true);
    $configuration->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', true);
    $configuration->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp', true);
    $configuration->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', array('span.style', '*.id', '*.src', 'a.href', 'table.style', 'img.style', 'td.colspan', 'td.rowspan', 'td.style'));
    $styles = array('margin-left', 'color', 'background-color', 'text-decoration', 'font-weight', 'font-style', 'border', 'border-collapse', 'height');
    $configuration->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', $styles);
    $htmlPurifier = new HTMLPurifier($configuration);
    return $htmlPurifier->purify($html);
```

Comment: Awesome. I have actually been using this to purify out scripts with the auto configuration but I did not know it could do all this. Thanks.